# Can the intersection of 2 non-regular languages ​be a regular and infinite language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

The outline of the exercise is this:
Describe two non-regular L1 and L2 languages on A = {a,b} such that L1∩L2 is infinite and regular.

The proposed solution to this exercise is:

**L1 = {a^n b^n | n > 0}**

**L2 = {a^n b^m | n != m AND word length is even}**

**L1∩L2 = {words of even length}**

What I don't understand, however, is that in L1 since n must be equal for both a and b we will always find words of the type aabb aaabbb ab aaaabbbb while in L2 n and m are different so we will find words of the type aaaabb abbbbb also respecting the condition that they are even, but in the intersection how do we find words of even length if the strings will never be equal, i.e. which string can belong to both L1 and L2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intersection of the languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ given is indeed empty.

To built a very simple example, let's do the following:

$$A := \{aaa^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{bw \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$$
$$B := \{aba^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{bw \mid w \in \{a,b,\}^*\}$$

Now we have that $A \cap B = b\{a,b\}^*$, which is clearly regular and infinite.

Answer (score 0):

If L1 is non-regular because something at the start and L2 is non-regular because something at the end:

```
L1 = a^n b^n a+ b+ ab, n >= 1
L2 = ab a+ b+ a^n b^n, n >= 1
```

then the intersection is ab a+ b+ ab and regular.